# "mount(2) system call failed", would any of the methods lead to file loss?

Tags: partitioning, mount, filesystem, backup

I am getting a error `mount(2) system call failed:Structure needs cleaning` while mounting a partition, would any of the methods lead to file loss?

["Structure needs cleaning" error - cannot mount partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910078/structure-needs-cleaning-error-cannot-mount-partition)

Here is a question which has already been answered, I am asking this question because that partition has some files which I didn't get enough time to backup, would I be able to recover the files using theses methods?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Your filesystem is *broken*, and needs to be fixed. There is no certainty that your files will be lost. And there is no certainty that your files will be unrecoverable. Delay is unwise. Plan what you need to look for after the fsck repair is complete, and plan which data recovery strategy you want to follow if a file is lost. Then chase everybody out of the room, take a deep breath, start the fsck repair, and be prepared to execute your plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed the issue for me

sudo fsck.ext4 -y /dev/sdaX

Here "X" should be replaced with the number of the partition you are trying to fix
and there was no file loss for me 
(note -y is there because I am too lazy to type yes everytime it asked)