# rm: cannot remove '/boot/initrd.img-*': Structure needs cleaning

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, kernel, dpkg

My Ubuntu 20.04 laptop somehow got into a state where `apt update` no longer works. Instead, running that gives the output:

```
Removing linux-image-5.4.0-73-generic (5.4.0-73.82~18.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-73-generic
rm: cannot remove '/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-73-generic': Structure needs cleaning
dkpg: error processing package linux-image.5.4.0-73-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-73-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exist status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.4.0-73-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Tried the following but the problem persists.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken  # gives the same error
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoremove                # gives the same error
```

What else can we try? Thanks!

---

`lsblk` Output:

```
nvme0n1      259:0    0   477G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1  259:1    0   976M  0 part  /boot
├─nvme0n1p2  259:2    0   7.6G  0 part  
│ └─encr_sd1 253:1    0   7.6G  0 crypt [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p3  259:3    0   477M  0 part  /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p4  259:4    0 467.9G  0 part  
  └─encr_sd0 253:0    0 467.9G  0 crypt /
```

Comment: Run `fsck`. See ["Structure needs cleaning" error - cannot mount partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910078/structure-needs-cleaning-error-cannot-mount-partition)

Comment: @user535733 Which partition should I perform `fsck` on? I've included the output of `lsblk` in the question

Comment: It's shown in your output: The /boot partition.