# Can’t load ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, kernel, mount, 22.04

I have been using Ubuntu 22.04 for a month. I don't know why, but suddenly this happened and now I can't open Ubuntu. Please help, I am struggling since 2 days.

This is my log:

```
0.105342] ×86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIos.
0.284293] platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1: Cmem Oxfed40000
-Oxfed40fff]
0.2843051 acp MSFT0101:00: platfor device creation failed: -16
0.4337933 integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
0.5736711 / dev/root: Can't open blockdeu
0.5737231 List of all bdeu filesystems:
0.573745]
ext3
0.5737481
ext2
0.5737611
ext4
0.5737741
squashfs
0.5737871
utat
0.573801]
0.5738141
fuseblk
0.5738391
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-blockto,0)
0.5738781
CPU: 2 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 6.5.0-14-generic #14 2.04.1-Ubuntu
0.573919] Harduare name: LENOVO 80S/Torronto 5C1, BIOS 3JCN31 07/17/2018
0.573953] Call Trace:
0.5739693
‹TASK>
0.5739861
0.574015J
dump_stack_lul+0x48/0x70
.5740381
dump_stack+0x10/0x20
574066J
panic+0x308/0x3a0
574098]
nount_root gener ic+0x1a5/0x340
574121)
mount_root+0x98/0x100
5741471
_pfx_kernel_init+0x10/0x10
0.5741771
prepare_namespace +0x6c/0x2c0
kernel_init_freeable+0x1c1/0x200
0.574204]
kernel_init+0x1b/0x200
0.5742261
ret_fron_fork+0x44/0x70
0.574253]
pix _kernel_init+0x10/0x10
0.5742781
ret_fron_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
0.574308]
«TASK>
0.5743811
Kernel Offset: 0x1a800000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: Oxffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
0.5744331
-I end Kernel panic - not syncing: UFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) J-
```

At first it was showing minimal a bash line. Then I tried something on the internet and that opened my Ubuntu, but then on restart it showed `grub>`. Then again I tried something and now it is showing me this.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: At first it was showing minimal bash line I tried something on internet and which opened my Ubuntu but then on restart it showed grub> then again i tried something and now it is showing me this what do i do please help

Comment: Error checking filesystem on /dev/sda4: Process reported exit code
12: e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
extfs_read _inode: Inode checksum does not match inode while reading inode 6292607 in process _bad inode e2fsck: aborted (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Comment: Also on mounting the partition it says Sorry, could not display all the contents of "71ab14c2-4F2a-4a54-bc84-89F65311c304": Error when getting information for file "/media/-ubuntu/71ab14c2-4f2a-4a54-bc84-89f65311c304/proc": Structure needs cleaning

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Structure needs cleaning" error - cannot mount partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910078/structure-needs-cleaning-error-cannot-mount-partition)

Comment: I am really new to ubuntu i don’t understand how do i do that

Comment: Nobody is born knowing how to backup their data and then run `fsck`. This is your opportunity to learn.

Comment: So i backed up my data entered ubuntu using my live usb and ran the fsck i think this is what i was supposed to do

Comment: Even after performing fsck nothing changed still getting the same error

Comment: If, after running `fsck`, you are still getting a "structure needs cleaning" error, then you did not run `fsck` completely or properly. Re-read the linked duplicate for advice how to fix "structure needs cleaning." If you need more interactive assistance, consider IRC ot UbuntuFourms, which are better suited for follow-up questions, tutoring, and one-on-one help.