Ubuntu 22.04 is stuck at Grub Rescue
My Dell 960 desktop has been running Ubuntu 22.04 for several months without any problems. Suddenly it stopped, and upon restart Grub Rescue came up. I'm unable to redirect boot with LS commands. I used a USB stick with Ubuntu 24.04 to reboot and loaded and ran Boot Repair. The results are at https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/y9cxnbT6rG/ .
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    biosdisk fshelp fat exfat ext2 ntfs ntfscomp part_msdos
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/sda1: mount(2) system call failed: Structure needs cleaning.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  MSWIN4.1: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: RV620 PRO [Radeon HD 3470] from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, noble, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: A06(5.0) from Dell Inc.
This live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 149.01 GiB, 160000000000 bytes, 312500000 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x00039e5f
     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *         2048 308375551 308373504  147G 83 Linux
sda2       308377598 312498175   4120578    2G  5 Extended
sda5       308377600 312498175   4120576    2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
Disk sdb: 14.65 GiB, 15728640000 bytes, 30720000 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x001fc462
     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *     2048 30719951 30717904 14.6G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:160GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA ST3160815AS:;
1:1049kB:158GB:158GB:ext4::boot;
2:158GB:160GB:2110MB:::;
5:158GB:160GB:2110MB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
sdb:15.7GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:USB DISK :;
1:1049kB:15.7GB:15.7GB:fat32::boot, lba;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                   
├─sda1 ext4     2fb459a8-e6d6-4071-8792-be88c6933883 00039e5f-01                                      
├─sda2                                               00039e5f-02                                      
└─sda5 swap     90b375f3-9597-4eb8-9611-4d79a726cba1 00039e5f-05                                      
sdb                                                                                                   
└─sdb1 vfat     A01F-2DAF                            001fc462-01                          UBUNTU 24_0 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1                8.9G  40% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sdb1              vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.

The line says "The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot." I am reluctant to try the advanced mode as I do not want to lose data on the drive if the wrong selections are chosen. Should I
a) Run the advanced mode without checking any options other than those already checked
b) Install Ubuntu 24 over the top of the current installation (do not want to lose other files on disk!)
c) Run other utilities or fixes (please suggest which ones and how to do this). One message in the above Pastebin says:
Mounting failed: mount: /mnt/BootInfo/sda1: mount(2) system call failed: 
Structure needs cleaning. 
dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

Is there a way to "clean the structure" without reloading Ubuntu?

version 22 and 24 would be versions of Ubuntu Core. If  you are not using Ubuntu Core please edit and put in the actual version info.

If your files are placed in the/home directory, delete all directories except /home, and reinstall Ubuntu 24.04 without formatting the partition

I might  try fsck on sda1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474846/fixing-bad-superblock-on-ssd-drive-is-e2fsck-safe-to-run Not sure if file system corrupted that you can over  install without formatting & losing data. If hardware failure then only recourse is new drive, and restore from backup. You do have good backups?

As @oldread See the answer @ https://askubuntu.com/questions/910078/structure-needs-cleaning-error-cannot-mount-partition
